# ClearCase: Query labels with specific attribute value

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

How can I query all labels that satisfy the list of conditions below?

- Label is NOT `locked` or `obsolete`
- Label has an attribube `My_Attribute` containing the value `myvalue`

Comment: It should be a case for  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm (ct lstype -king lbtype) Combined it with https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm. I'll post an answer later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cleartool lbtype -kind lbtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm) combined with [`fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).

That is:

```
cleartool lbtype -kind lbtype -fmt "%n Lock status: %[locked]p %a"
```

You can the grep the content for what you are looking for

```
grep -v locked 
grep -v obsolete
grep "My_Attribute=myvalue"
```

Comment: It is not exactly the "easy solution" I have been looking for, but I have not found other one. I recomend for the win users [grepWin](http://tools.stefankueng.com/grepWin.html) tool.